# Introductory to statistical mechanics text query

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

In the text "*Introduction to modern statistical mechanics*" by Chandler the following is stated in the first chapter:

> Entropy obeys several other important properties as well. To derive them, consider its differential $$dS = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_{\textbf{X}}dE + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \textbf{X}}\right)_{E}\cdot d \textbf{X}.$$ For a reversible process, we also have $$dE = (dQ)_{\text{rev}} + \textbf{f} \cdot d \textbf{X}.$$ Combining the last two equations gives $$dS = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_{\textbf{X}}(dQ)_{\text{rev}} + \left[\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \textbf{X}}\right)_{E} + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_{\mathbf{X}}\textbf{f}\right]\cdot d\textbf{X}.$$
>   For an adiabatic process that is reversible, we have that both $dS$ and $(dQ)_{\text{rev}}$ are zero. Since the last equation must hold for all reversible processes, it must hold for reversible adiabatic processes. To ensure this behaviors, the term in square brackets in the last equation must be identically zero. Hence $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \textbf{X}}\right)_{E} = -\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_{\textbf{X}}\textbf{f}.$$
>
> *Note that all the quantities involved in this equation are functions of state. Therefore, the equality holds for nonadiabatic as well as adiabatic processes.*

**Questions:**

- Just to confirm, is the partial derivative notation $\left(\frac{\partial \cdot}{\partial \cdot}\right)_{\mathbf{X}}$ simply just the partial derivative with the subscript $\mathbf{X}$ implying that we keep $\mathbf{X}$ constant?
- How does the fact that the quantities in the equation being functions of state imply that the equality holds for nonadiabatic as well as adiabatic processes?
- Does the last equation only hold for reversible processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes, it means to keep the subindex constant.

For the other two start with the [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) rule

$$
\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right)_z \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \right)_x \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)_y = -1
$$

Using $x = S$, $y = E$ and $z = {\bf X}$, you will find that

$$
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E} \right)_{\bf X}\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial {\bf X}} \right)_S = -\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial {\bf X}} \right)_E \tag{1}
$$

Now recall that

$$
{\rm d}E = T{\rm d}S + {\bf f}\cdot {\rm d}{\bf X} 
$$

which means that

$$
{\bf f} = \left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial {\bf X}} \right)_S \tag{2}
$$

Replace $(2)$ into $(1)$ to obtain

$$
{\bf f}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E} \right)_{\bf X} = -\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial {\bf X}} \right)_E \tag{3}
$$

which is the result you're looking for, without making the assumption the process is adiabatic or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there an assumption of reversibility or does the following derivation hold for non-adiabatic and irreversible processes?

Comment: @JohnDoe I do believe it also holds for irreversible systems

Comment: Thanks. When you state "Now recall that $$dE = TdS + \textbf{f}\cdot d \textbf{X}$$", is this derived or postulated?

Comment: @JohnDoe First Law of Thermodynamics

Comment: Okay, not sure if you have read Chandler but he derives that form of the equation as a consequence of your equation (3). But you are taking it as a postulate it seems hence my query...

Comment: @JohnDoe I haven't read him, but regardless, you need to start assuming something. Many authors assume $A$ and then conclude $B$, others prefer to use $B$ as a principle and then derive $A$, since the theory is self-consistent you can afford to do that. I will give it [Chandler] a look anyways

Comment: One last question. Am I correct in stating that for a reversible process it always follows that $dS = 0$?

Comment: @JohnDoe Not always, if the process is not adiabatic then ${\rm d}S$ may not be zero

Comment: So the statement requires that there is no heat or mass transfer from the system and it's surroundings, in other words it is required to be sufficiently isolated for reversible to imply $dS = 0$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86385/discussion-between-caverac-and-john-doe).